# how to stop background music on button click android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android and trying to add background music using below codes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MediaPlayer player;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("bg.mp3");
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

and now background music is running well. but I want to stop the background music using a image button click. but I am not getting any Idea how to do that. However I have tried the below but not working at all:

```
protected void stopmus(View view) {
        MediaPlayer player;
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            super.onStop();
            player.stop();
            player = null;

    }
```

please help me to solve it.

Comment: change the media player to instance var and not with a local scope. current you are creating a new object and calling stop on it ... which won't stop the original MediaPlayer object playing the track.

Comment: are `onCreate` & `stopmus` lie in same class ??

Comment: try to assign Mediaplayer player as a field variable..that means global variable..before the oncreate(). Then onCreate() initialize the variable like so -> player = new Mediaplayer(); play the music and on stop dont assign a new media player..just player.stop();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make MedaiPlayer **a global variable** declare it out side `onCreate()`.

```
MediaPlayer player;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Change yout stop method like this:

```
protected void stopmus(View view) {

        if(player!=null)
        {
            player.stop();
            player = null;
        }
        super.onStop(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Its working as expected. but at some mobile (Android Version 5) when I click the stop music button, the app suddenly exit without any error.

Comment: there could be something in logcat. Try to find out do that 2-3 times or restart your Android Studio.

Comment: there could be a device specific problem. Make sure you are not finishing all activities.!!